# Hibernate: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got this error when trying to update data using native SQL. This is my script:

```
update weight_note_receipt set pledge_id =:pledge  where wn_id in (:wns)
```

`wns` is the string that contains more than 1 `wn_id` like this:

```
222,226,228,251,256,262,263,264,265,266,267,272,281,286,294,296,299,301,302,303,306,307,330,332,333,337,338,339,341,368,371,376,377,378,379,380,381,385,391,397,423,424,443,452,454,461,462,463,464,490,503,504,521,525,528,529,530,532,533,549,554,560,561,564,565,566,567,569,570,595,598,600,603,605,606,607,644,646,649,653,661,662,663,667,669,678,683,752,1039,1075,258,259,260,261,268,269,270,287,304,305,308,325,334,604,643,647,648,659,660,664,665,666,704,709,753,754,757,758,809,834,846,861,872,879,882,911,913,916,919,920,164
```

When I update (using `query.executeUpdate()`), it throws the following error:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute native bulk
>   manipulation query] with root cause
>       com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
>   '222,226,228,251,256,262,263,264,265,266,267,272,281,286,294,296,299,301,302,303,306,307,330,332,333,337,338,339,341,368,371,376,'

Is it because the input string is too long?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When having parameterized queries in databases (prepared statements), assigning values to parameters MUST NOT change the structure and execution path of the query (otherwise databases don't treat them as parameterized queries and will throw exception).

That's why you can't have prepared statements for queries like:

- `select * from myTable order by ?`
- `select id, f1, ? from myTable`
- `select * from ?`.

because assigning a value to each parameter changes the query execution path (remember that prepared statements' query is parsed once and results a single execution path).

The same rules applies to Hibernate query parser, you shall not assign a parameter a value which changes the query structure.

Assigning an string with values `1, 2, 3` to a SHOULD-TO-BE-A-NUMBER parameters is just the same, in fact the first query will be translated just the same as `update weight_note_receipt set pledge_id =:pledge  where wn_id = :wns` but the second one will be translated as `update weight_note_receipt set pledge_id =:pledge  where (wn_id = :x1 or wn_id = :x2 or wn_id = :x3)`, obviously different queries with different execution paths.

So even if Hibernate did not throw an exception, your database would.

Comment: I still not understand something, but your solution worked well, thanks a lot

Comment: And what is the remaining problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the SQLQuery Hibernate API, you could use the `setParameterList(PARAM, COLLECTION)` method.

Your query string can remain the same with its `in` clause and braces.

Comment: It MUST remain the same. Without the braces it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If client is sending a data which size is more than the size specified in the database , then  it throws org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query         at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException..