# query must begin with select or from: update

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using this code for update occupation but I'm getting an error like query must begin with `select or from : update` so please help me:

```
public static void changeOccup(String email,String occup){
 try{  Session sess=UtilClass.createSession();
  Transaction tx=sess.beginTransaction();Query que=sess.createQuery("update Userrecord set occupation=occup where emailId=email");
  que.setParameter("occup", occup);
  que.setParameter("email", email);
  int result=que.executeUpdate();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"occup changed"+result);
    tx.commit();
 }
```

Comment: also used this query but not working:    Query que=sess.createQuery("update Userrecord set occupation=:occup where emailId=:email");

Comment: Query que=sess.createQuery("update Userrecord set occupation=:occup"+"where emailId=:email");    tried this also but same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem solved.. i have used method update of session

```
public static void changeOccup(String email,String occup){Session sess=null;try{sess=UtilClass.createSession();Transaction tr=sess.beginTransaction();Userrecord u=(Userrecord) sess.get(Userrecord.class, email); u.setOccupation(occup); sess.update(u);tr.commit();}catch(Exception e){} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SQLQuery` and `createSQLQuery` instead of `Query` and `createQuery`.  If you're using `Query` and `createQuery` you have to use Hibernate's syntax.  If you want regular SQL syntax, use `SQLQuery`.

Comment: and for sql query i have to use pojo class or database table??

Comment: i have used SQLQuery and createSQLQuey but it gives me error like : could not execute bulk manipulation query..

Comment: in my cfg.xml file i m using :  hibernate.query.factory_class org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory .. if i change it from thi to hibernate.query.factory_class org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory then my select and insert query doesnt work..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625692/hibernate-could-not-execute-native-bulk-manipulation-query